# Vertical line in ion-item list

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic and html and I'm trying to put a vertical line inside a ion-item in ion-list. I want something like this (the colored line after 'all-day'): https://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/IMG_1723-640x360.jpg

I have tried something like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor=let item of items>
    <div class="verticalLine"></div>
    <div class="line-break">{{ item.longStringFromTSFile }}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

// INSIDE SCSS FILE
.verticalLine {
  width:1%;
  height:75%;
  background:green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

But the vertical lines sometimes is too long, as you can see from this photo: [verticalLines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obq29.png)

What I really want is this:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEERZ.png)

EDIT: Vertical line are not equals: [new photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxELW.png)

Comment: okay so what is the actual result expected?  because vertical line right now increase its height proportionaly to the text , if text will be `demo` vertical line also will be small , if text is'tooo big ' the verical line also will be too long , that is why I want you to give us a actual result how excatly it should look having small text or big text

Answer (score 4):

Try something like [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eyztoa)

HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span item-start style="width:50px;">{{item.name}}</span>
    <div class="verticalLine"></div>
    <div item-end >{{item.age}}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

css:

```
.verticalLine {
  width:1%;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Now is better, but I have always some trouble (look at the new photo). Some line is thinner than other, and the lines that separates the item are deleted or very small.

Comment: please accept  solution if it helped   so other ca find it easily. thanks

Comment: This is not the perfect solution that I want, as I said, there are stil problems

Comment: hii <div item-end style="width:100px" >{{item.age}}</div> will solve your problem

you need to fix the width of contents that's why  lines are not aligned

Comment: I've solve that problem adding an ion-item-divider, but the green vertical lines are still different between them... I've tried with width: 3px (in css), but it doesn't work. Any idea? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
.verticalLine {
  width:1%;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

remember setting `height 75%` will be proportional to how big text is it.

Comment: Precisely what I want is that the line is perfectly at the center of each item (I've added a photo), and cover all the text